# How to style data from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, styles, comments

I got this PHP code to display comments from database:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con){
    die("cannot connect: " . mysql_error());
  } 
  mysql_select_db("strek", $con);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM comments";  
  $result=mysql_query($sql, $con);

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $comment=$row['comment'];
    echo $name. "<br>" .$comment;
    echo"<br>";
  }
?>
```

I'd like both name and comment to be aligned in the center and I'd like name to be BOLD.
Please help me how to do that.

Comment: You output appropriate markup and link an appropriate stylesheet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — `<center>`? That was deprecated in the 90s.

Comment: `<center>` helps me keeping stuff in the middle :) perfect semantical tag :)

Comment: The `align` attribute was deprecated at the same time as the `center` element. CSS was introduced in 1996, support for it is pretty good these days.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Using inline `align` has been terrible practice since the 90s

Comment: @Quentin: Who say that websites with that HTML should not be working any longer? HTML is not a programming language. Even there are updates and it is said that some things are "deprecated" (it might be that there was a misunderstanding in the W3C about what that acutally is in hyptertext), it's there to stay for eternity.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Really stop commenting before reading a bit on CSS / HTML

Comment: @hakre — The center element has no semantics whatsoever. Nobody is saying that websites written in the 90s should stop working, they are saying that you shouldn't write websites as if it was still the 90s.

Comment: @PeeHaa Well be my guest then. I see a whole bunch of comments "against" what I try to help out with, I don't see you guys doing anything.

Comment: @PeeHaa *"Really stop commenting before reading a bit on CSS / HTML"* --- FYI, I am well aware of it. I like to use `<center></center>` because it's "quick & dirty" and uses less space than a `<div`. It works for me, in all browsers, and like Quentin said, why should they stop working any longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I'd like both name and comment to be aligned in the center and I'd like name to be BOLD. Please help me how to do that."*

Since the OP already has double quotes in `echo $name. "<br>" .$comment;` in what I think is already working and needs to have it centered and in bold, the use of my code below is perfectly valid.

Consider the following:

```
echo "<div align='center'><b>" . $name. "<br>" .$comment . "</b></div>";
```

A working example:

```
<?php

$name = "John";

$comment = "This is a comment";

echo "<div align='center'><b>" . $name. "<br>" .$comment . "</b></div>";

?>
```

You could also make use of a stylesheet with either a DIV ID, and/or a CLASS.

For example:

```
echo "<div align='center' id='names_comments' class='centered bold_text'>" . $name. "<br>" .$comment . "</div>";
```

Then using CSS:

```
#names_comments {
font-family:Georgia;
font-size:12pt;
}

.centered bold_text {
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Note: `align='center'` could be omitted, but it won't hurt to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     <span style="display: block;">
         <span style="font-weight: bold; width: 100px; display: inline-block;">
             <?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES);?>
         </span>
         <span style="text-align: center; width: 200px; display: inline-block;">
             <?php echo htmlspecialchars($result['comment'], ENT_QUOTES);?>
         </span>
     </span>
}
```

Function htmlspecialchars - convert special characters to HTML entities. With flag ENT_QUOTES escape quotes in order to avoid broke HTML code.

Comment: Why display: block spans instead of divs? The other spans won't have their specified `width` or `text-align` values applied as they are still `display: inline`. This answer would be better if you explained the purpose of `htmlspecialchars` (although adding it is probably the right thing to do) and used a real stylesheet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — Why are you moaning about that at me on someone else's answer? If you want my opinion on how you can improve your answer, then read the comments on the question from before you wrote it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 <span style="text-align:center">
     <b>
         <?= $row['name']?>
     </b>
         <?= $row['comment']?>
 </span>
}
```

Comment: The `text-align` property doesn't apply to elements that are `display: inline` (which span elements are by default).